# Shapes defined by points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, discrete-geometry, euclidean-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, similarity

Can shapes determined by some number of points?

From an amazing [theorem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00151519) in plane curves geometry we know that vertices of triangles similar to arbitrary triangle $T$ is **dense** on every closed jordan curve in a plane, so if $J$ be such curve and $A,B,C$ be 3 noncollinear points on plane then at least one curve similar to $J$ contains $A,B,C$. If $J$ be a circle then exactly one circle passes through $A,B,C$. From here we reach the problem in its simplest form:

> **QUESTION:** Is circle the only shape on an **Euclidean** plane (not only from closed curves mentioned above) which **just one similar to it** to be defined by each set of 3 non-collinear points we consider from $\mathbb{R}^2$ ? *(Means not two or more similar of the shape fits $A,B,C$, just one of it).*

**Note:** here for a refined question we take the mentioned "shape" as one dimensional connected curve. The "trivial triangle" trivially could not be an answer because we can find infinitely many similar of it passing through the 3 points which creates it as vertices.

What about generalization to $n$ points in **$\mathbb{R}^m$** which exactly define **$k$** similar shapes?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson for equilateral triangle we have 3 two_thirds of a circle passing through its vertices, so it could not be an answer, just whole of a circle satisfies the condition not any part of it.

Comment: Please, "collinear", not "colinear".

Comment: @GerryMyerson : odd, in French it only has one "l"; I wonder why that is

Comment: @Max, the English-speaking peoples are more affluent than the French, and can better afford the luxury of extra letters.

Comment: @GerryMyerson My preferred interpretation is that there's only one letter-l, but we also include a vertical line to remind students what it means.

Comment: Maybe it helps to think about, given such a shape $\mathcal{S}$, for each triple of noncollinear points $A,B,C\in\mathcal{S}$ the space of all triples $A',B',C'\in\mathcal{S}$ with $\triangle ABC\sim\triangle A'B'C'$? Intuitively, these would have to all be related to each other via symmetries of $\mathcal{S}$, and maybe that gives some leverage in analyzing $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson In Merriam–Webster, *colinear* is also [OK](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colinear).